# JSF 2 and Primefaces attribute Ajax=false

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a form that has a commandlink that opens a modal dialog, the dialog has an inputtext and a button saved, when I enter a value in the inputtext, this value has to be copied to another inputtext in the first form, but the attribute update doesn't update the inputtext in the first form, I have to put attribute ajax="false" in the button save of the dialog for that reload the page, so the value in the inputtext of the dialog is copied to the inputtext of the first form. I want to know if there is another way to update this value without the attribute ajax="false" and doesn't reload the page

create_store.xhtml

```
<ui:composition  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

<h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%" border="0" columnClasses="colC1,colC2">
    <h:outputText  value="Code: " style="margin-right:20px;"/>  
    <p:inputText id="idCodProvider" value="#{storeBean.au.code}" size="84"/>

    <h:outputText  value="Name: " style="margin-right:20px;"/>  
    <p:inputText id="idName" value="#{storeBean.au.name}" size="84"/>

    <p:commandLink id="idAdressLink" style="margin-right:20px;" actionListener="#{storeBean.selectAdress}" 
                   update=":idFormAdress:idPgADressStore" >  
         <h:outputText value="Adress:" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:inputText id="idAdressStore" label="Adress" value="#{storeBean.au.adressStore}" size="84"/>
    <h:outputText value="&#160;&#160;&#160;" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

dialog_adress.xhtml

```
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:panelGrid id="idPgAdressStore" columns="2" columnClasses="col1,col2">
    <h:outputLabel for="idAdress" value="Adress: " />  
    <p:inputText id="idAdress"  label="Adress" size="40" value="#{adressBean.au.strAdress}"/>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="2" style="text-align:center">
            <p:commandButton id="idBtSaveDir" value="Save" actionListener="#{storeBean.saveAdress}" 
                             update=":idFormAdress,:idFormStore" onComplete="PF('dlgDirStore').hide()"/>
            <p:commandButton id="idBtCancelDir" value="Cancel" type="button" onclick="PF('dlgDirStore').hide()"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: What you wantto achieve is perfectly legal. I assume that: 1. storeBean.saveAdress copies the value to storeBean.au.adressStore field; 2. idAdressStore and idAdress inputs are in two separate h:form-s; 3. there are no nested h:forms in your code; 4. :idFormStore correctly points to the form containing the field you want updated - is that right?

Comment: You are ok, there are two forms, idFormStore works in create_store.xhtml with idAdressStore and idFormAdress works in dialog_adress.xhtml with idAdress

Comment: I'd try update=":#{p:component('fieldId')}" to make sure there's no problem with identifying the right field. I'd also change onComplete to oncomplete (does it work this way?). I can't find anything that could really cause this problem - but there's  an example of this kind of update in the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf - maybe it would help you spot the difference yourself.

Comment: You are ok again,I wrote bad here,but in my code is oncomplete.I'm working with a template that have a tree in the left side and an outputpanel in the right side, the outputpanel contains to create_store.xhtml,so I can changed between the branchs of the tree, when I work with create_store.xhtml the first time works fine,but I changed to another branch and return to the branch of create_store.xhtml the dialog have the problem for updating with ajax, I have to reload the page or put ajax="false" for that works well,but I want to know another way of to update without ajax="false", @The Apprentice

Comment: My tip is, that there are wrong `update` attribute values. Try udpate="@all". If it works try to track what are the correct ids of your components.